# Why is this happening in Python when using random? How can I prevent it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I want to create 128 keys consisting of random bits. Each key must have size = 128 bits. When I run the following code I notice this strange output:

**CODE:**

```
for i in range(1, 128):
    key = random.getrandbits(128)
    print("Key:", key, key.bit_length())
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Key: 171015864459493129154336425209795162216 128
Key: 265655405161066827301254922985896430579 128
Key: 149533773555250911787517288984005312306 127
Key: 67337979537475290133339561382641205404 126
Key: 309944504326722665064876901817102187588 128
Key: 5025567194209335595020257770351824725 122
Key: 311246876593534253598386348380900720669 128
etc
```

Why do some keys have length smaller than 128? How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the random bits can be either 0 or 1  so when  the bits at the left are 0 ( half of the time ) the number will be still generated but with length < 128 
which is very logic

Answer (score 3):

`random` generates a random python long with the given amount of random bits, as the docs explains.

> random.getrandbits(k)
>
> Returns a python long int with k random bits. [...]

The method you are using is documented as follows:

> long.bit_length()
>
> Return the number of bits necessary to represent an integer in binary, excluding the sign and leading zeros.

Therefore the shorter numbers are in fact random numbers with some leading zeroes which are not included in the count.

Note that the use of `random` for security purposes is discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

As a side note `for i in range(1, 128)` will only give you 127 keys. Simple fix with `for i in range(0, 128)`

(I would prefer to add as comment, not enough rep to do so)

Comment: Ironically I can comment now